# React variable REACT_APP_API_HOST is not an internal or external command

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am a beginner in React project and trying to run a project using `yarn start` but I get this error:

```
D:\Projects\Demo>yarn start
yarn run v1.7.0
$ REACT_APP_API_HOST=https://us-central1-mydemo.cloudfunctions.net/ react-s
cripts start
'REACT_APP_API_HOST' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

and this is what is there in package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "REACT_APP_API_HOST=https://us-central1-mydemo.cloudfunctions.net/ react-scripts start"
}
```

How do I fix this error? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on Windows, it can sort of choke when it comes to environment variables. I recommend getting the cross-env package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) and changing your start script to:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "cross-env REACT_APP_API_HOST=https://us-central1-mydemo.cloudfunctions.net/ react-scripts start"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
you have to use your environment variable define in `.env` file and access in our app.

.env file 

    REACT_APP_API_HOST=https://us-central1-mydemo.cloudfunctions.net/

app.js

use env variable in app.js file.

    console.log('REACT_APP_API_HOST',${process.env.REACT_APP_API_HOST});
```

> O/P : https://us-central1-mydemo.cloudfunctions.net/

Comment: Sorry did not follow. The problem is REACT_APP_API_HOST is defined in package.json in scripts start so yarn start is not working.

Comment: why u have to define REACT_APP_API_HOST in script start. remove REACT_APP_API_HOST  and start it will be work

Comment: But why to remove? The project has been developed by somebody else and as per this link https://medium.com/@tacomanator/environments-with-create-react-app-7b645312c09d it should work?

Comment: you can clear your things by checking Keith's answer. It is what was required.